# I don't get mobile SE on my iPhone?

Tags: support, mobile-web

I have mobile safari on my iPhone 5, but I don't get the mobile theme on Stack Overflow.

Is there any way to force mobile theme? The regular theme is causing me an issue for Ask Different. Ask Different Meta is Mobile theme for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure.

Look at the footer. There is a link there - "mobile". Click it to force the mobile theme.

[image: mobile link in desktop site footer]

And in the mobile theme, click the "full site" link to get back to the non-mobile version.

[image: full site link in mobile footer]

Comment: That's really quick and thanks.